# Keyatm covariate model gives me same result of the predicted mean of the document-topic distribution for four different country categories

Tags: r, text, topic-modeling

I have four different groups of countries, I would assume that the predicted mean of the document-topic distribution differs over countries. Yet i get the same results.

I run this code (pretty much in line with keyatm's user guide):

```
     `strata_LI <- by_strata_DocTopic(out, by_var = "CountriesLI",labels = 
      c("Non-LI", "LI")
      )
      strata_LMI <- by_strata_DocTopic(out, by_var = "CountriesLMI",labels = 
      c("Non-LMI", "LMI")
      )
      strata_UMI <- by_strata_DocTopic(out, by_var = "CountriesUMI",labels = 
      c("Non-UMI", "UMI")
      )
      strata_HI <- by_strata_DocTopic(out, by_var = "CountriesHI",labels = 
      c("Non-HI", "HI")
       )

      est_LI <- summary(strata_LI)
      est_LMI <- summary(strata_LMI)
      est_UMI <- summary(strata_UMI)
      est_HI <- summary(strata_HI)
      
      new_data <- covariates_get(out)new_data
      new_data[, "CountriesLI"] <- 0
      new_data[, "CountriesLMI"] <- 0
      new_data[, "CountriesUMI"]<- 0
      new_data[, "CountriesHI"]<- 0
      pred <- predict(out, new_data, label = "Group")

      res <- bind_rows(est_LI, est_LMI, est_UMI,est_HI, pred)

      pred_LI <- predict(out, new_data, label = "CountriesLI")
      pred_LMI <- predict(out, new_data, label = "CountriesLMI")
      pred_UMI <- predict(out, new_data, label = "CountriesUMI")
      pred_HI <- predict(out, new_data, label = "CountriesHI")

      res <- bind_rows(est_LI, est_LMI, est_UMI, est_HI, pred_LI, pred_LMI, 
      pred_UMI, pred_HI, pred) 
      %>%filter(TopicID %in% c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13))

      labels <- unique(res$label)
      library(ggplot2)
      ggplot(res, aes(x = label, ymin = Lower, ymax = Upper, group = Topic)) 
      +geom_errorbar(width = 0.1) 
      +coord_flip() 
      +facet_wrap(~Topic) + 
      geom_point(aes(x = label, y = Point)) 
      +scale_x_discrete(limits = rev(labels))
      +xlab("Countries") 
      +ylab(expression(paste("Mean of ", theta))) + 
      theme_bw()`
```

Comment: It would help if you format your code correctly. Just one big code block. And it seems like you have multiple statements in some of the lines.

Comment: Hi, thank you - adjusted the format.